# Нарисовать пирамидки javascript

Tags: javascript, javascript-events, javascript-faq

Помогите нарисовать пирамидки javascript. 
Заранее спасибо.

Comment: а есть какие-нибудь свои мысли по этому поводу?

Comment: щас решу, минуточку

Comment: а че Вы картинку убрали? Пусть люди видят задачу

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
console.log(draw(4))
console.log(draw(6, 2))
console.log(draw(6, 2, true))
console.log(draw(6, 2) + draw(6, 2, true))

/**
 * Рисует пирамиду
 *
 * size - размер
 * plus - сколько добавлять к толщине за шаг
 * reverse - перевернутая?
 *
 * Возвращает строку пирамиды (конкатенации всех строчек)
 */
function draw (size, plus = 1, reverse = false) {
  let resultArr = []
  
  // в зависимости от перевернутости выбирает цикл
  for (let i = size; i >= 0; i -= plus)
    row(i)
  
  if (reverse)
    resultArr = resultArr.reverse()
    
  // в конце еще добавляю чтобы можно было конкатенировать пирамиды
  return resultArr.join('\n') + '\n'
  
  // рисует ряд
  function row (i) {
    // строка ряда, изначально переменная содержит левый отступ + "*"
    let rowStr = addRow(i)

    // рисовать правую часть если сейчас не верхушка
    if (i < size) {
      // отступ для правой части
      const add = (size - i) * 2

      // добавляет правую часть
      rowStr += addRow(add - 1)
    }

    // добавляет к результату
    resultArr.push(rowStr)
  }
  
  function addRow (repeat) {
    return ' '.repeat(repeat) + '*'
  }
}
```